# Has anyone used JMeter when authenticating with Auth0?

Tags: oauth, jmeter

I recorded the actions of logging into a website that uses Auth0 authentication. When I run the script in Jmeter I can see that the Auth0 authentication is not successful. Has anyone been able to successfully create a script in Jmeter that works with Auth0?

Thanks

Comment: (I work for auth0) Tell me more about how your application integrates with auth0 and I will give you a meaningful answer. Feel free to jump into chat.auth0.com

Answer (score 0):

Have your seen [Auth0 Load Tests](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-load-tests) project at GitHub?

It looks like that you shouldn't be needing anything but combination of

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

  with
- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm)

(both of them are a must for more or less complex web application to do sessions, cookie-based authentication and correlation)

to get Auth0 access token which you could reuse for your tests.

Comment: I work for Auth0. The load tests projects is something we did to try an isolated cluster, we did exactly what you described here, but this require a type of connection (identity provider) called Mock that is not available in the API/UI. Also, auth0 will apply a ban by ip address automatically in this case. You can approach us in chat.auth0.com and we might provide some options depending how you integrate with us, hope this help!